# Expression in where clause for merge condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table have one column named **Type** , is there any way to merge two condition in where close.

base table

```
select Amount,Type,IsVisibleToCustomer,Status from LiveCustomerTransaction


declare @Type int=0;

--@Type=1

select * from LiveCustomerTransaction where Type in (1,4,5)

--@Type=2,3

select * from LiveCustomerTransaction where Type=@Type
```

How to merge Type 1 and 2,3 condition in where close when @type is 1 then only 1,4,5 types are selected, when type is 2 or 3 then 2 or 3 are selected.

Comment: `where Type in (1,4,5, @Type)` ?

Comment: You defined @Type as int you can't set like this @Type=2,3.

Comment: @devil_coder , thanks for your reply, yes i know in int type can not put comma separated string. here only input is 1 or 3 or 2

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
select * from LiveCustomerTransaction
where ( @Type=1        and Type in (1,4,5) )
or    ( @Type in (2,3) and Type in ( 2,3 ) )
```

In this, 2 and 3 are interchangable (so Type is not necessarily the same as @Type, both should be either 2 or 3). If you meant it a bit more strict then it becomes this:

```
select * from LiveCustomerTransaction
where ( @Type=1        and Type in (1,4,5) )
or    ( @Type in (2,3) and Type=@Type      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following query

```
select * 
from LiveCustomerTransaction 
WHERE (@Type=1 and Type in (1,4,5))
      OR (@Type in (2,3) and Type = @Type)
```